# Razor and if statement

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, razor-2

I'm using MS Razor in MVC 3 C#, I need to display some text "hello" within the IF statement.
At the moment I receive an error. Any idea how to solve it?

EDIT: syntax error

```
   @if(Model.IsCustomEvent)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {  id=Model.EventTitle }) hello
    }
```

Comment: argh! ***WHAT ERROR!?***

Comment: my apologies, i have forgotten to include the error, i edited my question, please consider remove your down vote. thanks

Comment: In addition to the answers provided, you can also use the `<text></text>` tags for string literals. E.g: `@Html.ActionLink(...) <text>hello</text>`

Comment: Please consider adding a comment when down vote, in this way I can improve my questions. thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you need to put `:` before hello

```
 @if(Model.IsCustomEvent)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {  id=Model.EventTitle }) @:hello
    }
```

[Here is a good reference](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx)

Comment: Read the article for Razor syntax

Answer (score 4):

Use the `@:` [symbol for including literals](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/15/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax.aspx)

```
@if(Model.IsCustomEvent)
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {  id=Model.EventTitle }) 
    @:hello
}
```